# SwiperRefreshLayout arrow indicator not showing

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I have this problem, the first time I'm swiping down to show the spinner the arrow indicator is not showing:

**This is happening because of the RecyclerView because with a simple ListView is not happening.**

[image: Bug happening]

How I want to be:

[image: Fixed bug]

This is the SwipeRefreshLayout XML:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout_pitchList"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView_pitchList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

I really hope you can help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.colorPrimaryDark,R.color.colorPrimaryDark,R.color.colorPrimaryDark, R.color.colorPrimaryDark, R.color.colorPrimaryDark);

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

and go to res/values check you color theme...

```
   <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item> 
   </style>
```